# MYSQL and PHP output data limit

Tags: php, mysqli

When retrieving data from a MYSQL server it seems to be limiting the output results. Please refer to the following attachments

Code:

```
<style>
tr,td {
    border:1px red solid;
}
</style>
<?php
    include('./connect.php');

    if (!$connect) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connect, db_name);

    if (!$db_selected) {
        die('Can\'t use ' . db_name . ': ' . mysql_error());
    }   
    //execute the SQL query and return records
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * From jobs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

    echo "<table style='border:1px solid red'>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<tr><td>Reference Number:</td><td>'; echo $row['ID'];'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>First Name:</td><td>'; echo $row['FirstName'];'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>LastName:</td><td>'; echo $row['LastName'];'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Phone Numbner:</td><td>'; echo $row['Phone'];'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Email:</td><td>'; echo $row['Email'];'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Items:</td><td>'; echo $row['Items'];'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>Fault:</td><td style="width:100%">'; echo $row['Issue'];'</td></tr>';

    }
    echo "</table>";

    //close connection
    mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Output results:

```
Connected successfully
Reference Number:   100000
First Name: Jane
LastName:   Doe
Phone Numbner:  3372555897
Email:  janedoe@unknown.com
Items:  laptop
Fault:  Client states her laptop will no longer power on. However, p
```

as you can see under the fault heading there should be more to what is displaying.

Comment: Well first up you're not outputting your `</td></tr>` strings at the end of the line (if this is exact code).  Whether your browser is compensating for this or creating a large nest model is hard to say.  But then you don't echo "Connected successfully" anywhere, so I'm guessing this isn't *the* code

Comment: I think the browser is compensating. I have fixed up the missing echo with no change.
the echo connect comes from the include('./connect.php');

Comment: sidenote: you're mixing with `mysql_error()` that should read as `mysqli_error($connect)`

Comment: thanks Fred. I didn't notice that mistake either, this code was an old copy of my code that went missing and re modified old backup code that I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the reason of this and it only clicked after i posted my responses. I had a 64vchar limit in mysql table. Changed it to 1024 and now works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple errors with your output.

```
echo '<tr><td>Reference Number:</td><td>'; echo $row['ID'];'</td></tr>';
                                                        ^^^^^^
                                                    Missing echo
```

This occurs on every row and will cause layout errors which may be hiding your content.

Comment: echo's have been added no change in the output.

Comment: Can you update your question with the HTML output of this code?